# Very basic login form in html

Tags: html, forms, authentication

I want to make a very very basic login form.
So I have 2 textboxes (username and password)
And when the text equals, for example, admin and admin u get linked to a new page. I don't want it to get it from a database, just 1 username and 1 password will do.

It might sound stupid, but I forgot how to do it.
Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Have you tried something ? Because where do you want your login and pwd to be stored if you don't want to use a db ?

Comment: Google : `html php form login`. I found the answer to the first link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a basic login form code.

If this is fine mark it as answer.

```
if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login'] =='Login')
{
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    if($user=='admin' && $pass='abcd')
    {
        // your success code
    }
    else
    {
        //your error code
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <table>
        <caption>Login Form</caption>

            <tr>
                <td>User</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="user" value="" placeholder="User Name" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pass" value="" placeholder="User Name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></td>

            </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript!

get the username value and password
and check whether both are equal using 
document.formname.user equals to document.formname.pass?(password)